# Show that if $\gcd\left(a(x), \left(x^n-1\right)/g(x)\right)=1$, then $a(x)g(x)$ is a generator of the cyclic code $C$

Tags: coding-theory

Let $g(x)$ be the generator polynomial of a binary cyclic code $C$ and let
$h(x)=\left(x^{n}-1\right)/g(x)$ be the parity check polynomial.
Show that if $a(x)$ is a polynomial satisfying $\gcd\left(a(x), h(x)\right)=1$, then $a(x)g(x)$ is a generator of $C$.

Now what I am not understanding is why I must show that $a\left(x\right)$ will have to satisfy $\gcd\left(a(x), h(x)\right)=1$. As long as $a(x)$ is of least degree and a divisor of $x^n -1$, the polynomial $a(x)g(x)$ should be a generator of $C$, correct?

As always, thanks for the help.

Comment: You are asked to prove that **if** $\gcd(a(x),h(x)) = 1$, **then** every codeword polynomial is a multiple of $a(x)g(x)$. You don't need to understand _why_ $\gcd(a(x),h(x)) = 1$. It is the premise. What you need to prove is that if the premise is true, then the conclusion is also true.

Comment: Is it because $\gcd\left(a(x), h(x)\right)=1 \implies a(x)g(x)+h(x)b(x)=1$ and because $g(x)$ is a generator in $C$, then so will $a(x)g(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the gcd condition does not hold you won’t obtain the same ideal as $C=<g(x)>.$

Comment: Could you elaborate? I really appreciate your help!